# Prove that f has a right-hand limit at every point c in [a, b) and that f has a left-hand limit at every point c in (a, b].

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Question: Let f be an increasing function on [a, b] (that is, if x < y and , then f(x) < f(y)). Prove that f has a right-hand limit at every point c in [a, b) and that f has a left-hand limit at every point c in (a, b].

My thoughts: Is it sufficient to prove that if f is an increasing function on some interval [a, b], then left-hand limit and right-hand limit always exist for every x ∈ (a, b)?

Alternatively, how do I write a proof for the question? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: draw a picture and pick a candidate for each limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

1. For $c \in [a,b)$, prove that
   $$l = \inf \lbrace f(x), x > c \rbrace$$

is well-defined and is the right hand limit of $f$ when $x$ tends to $c^+$.

2. For $c \in (a,b]$, prove that
   $$l = \sup \lbrace f(x), x < c \rbrace$$

is well-defined and is the left hand limit of $f$ when $x$ tends to $c^-$.